# Authentication for Users using my Website API

Tags: api, cakephp, authentication, backbone.js, authorization

I am trying to get my head around how to implement security in a website API I am creating. Let me explain the design of my application.

I am writing an online invoicing application to allow users to create, store and send invoices. The application is split into 2 parts, the front end where the user enters and views their invoices etc... and the back-end that handles all the processing of the site (saving, updating data etc...)

What I am stuck on is how to implement some kind of security for my website so the user will enter either user name and password and then be authenticated on the back-end and the back-end will know which user is talking to it (hope this makes sense)

The front end communicates with the back-end via a RESTful API but when the front end sends a request to the API, how does the back-end know who the user is and if the user is allowed to access the API.

My front end is written using Backbone.js and communicates with the back-end API using JSON. The back-end is written in CakePHP

Answer (score 2):

there are several APIs auth patterns out there, you can read more about it here https://support.3scale.net/howtos/api-configuration/authentication-patterns , specially the section "Standard Authentication Patterns"

you basically will have to give users a secret token, then on the API calls the requests send that token to the backend, that way you can correlate users in both ends

if you are like me and want to save yourself all the implementation hassle you can use 3scale free accounts (http://www.3scale.net) to manage auth for you, by doing so you'll even have access control, limits on the API calls, and so on. Find more details here: http://www.3scale.net/2012/06/the-10-minute-api-up-running-3scale-grape-heroku-api-10-minutes/

the example uses the ruby plugin, but a php one is available also in GH github.com/3scale/3scale_ws_api_for_php